# Не удалось обновить веб-ссылку localhost

Tags: asp.net

У меня есть веб-узел созданный в VS 2010. Я добавляю в проект веб-службу созданную в этом же проекте. Все работает прекрасно до тех пор, пока я не переношу проект в другое место на компьютере. При этом выходит ошибка: *Не удалось обновить веб-ссылку "localhost.WebService".
Возникла ошибка при загрузке "http://localhost:2555/Frenzy/WebService.asmx?disco".
Невозможно соединиться с удаленным сервером
Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение 127.0.0.1:2555
Произошла ошибка при загрузке ''http://localhost:2555/Frenzy/WebService.as(0x80131509)*

Приходится удалять веб-ссылку и заново добавлять. Как можно этого избежать? Просто если я передам мой проект другому человеку, то мне придется ему говорить как обновлять веб-ссылку, хотя он понятия об этом не имеет и хочет просто чтобы запустился проект.

Answer (score 1):

как вариант, захостите сервис на отдельном сайте на IIS

Comment: Макс Жуков, дело в том что это дипломная работа, и у проверяющего может и не быть доступа к интернету. Такие вот древние места тоже остались. Есть ли ещё какие-нибудь варианты?

Comment: @skyboy, попробуйте после переноса солюшена в другую папку очистить солюшн и заново сбилдить. по идее все dll тогда пересоберутся.